# Can I embed C functions in COBOL?

Tags: c, function, cobol

I understand there is a way to call c functions from a COBOL program. However, is it possible to embed C functions in a COBOL Program?

I need this as certain environment parameters change when a C function is called from outside.

Comment: Which compiler?  Which operating system?

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux,
Pro*COBOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way!

Consider the Pro*COBOL Program (foo.pco) calling a function ( MyFunc() ) in bar.c.
Generate the object file from the C file as:
   $gcc -g -O -fPIC -c bar.c

Usage of the CALL statement in the Pro*COBOL ( COBOL ) code can be learnt from [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.cbl.doc%2Ftpsubw20.htm).

In case of Pro*COBOL, generate the .cob file using procob.
Then, use 
`$cob ...list of libraries... bar.o`

That should generate the executable!